# sonarqube server failed to sonar-scanner execution

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to analyze my code with sonarqube server but I got following error.

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on  http://192.168.0.70:9000/api
 /ce/submit?projectKey=mvctest_git&projectName=mvctest_git : {"errors": [{"msg":"F
    ail to insert data of CE task AVjxlgQMTxoM_vEXvBke"}]}
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse
   .java:36)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsC
     lient.java:102)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:71)

    at org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:
     173)
    at org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java
    :128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(Publis
    hPhaseExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.executeOnRoot(PublishPh
    aseExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseE
    xecutor.java:81)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanCon
    tainer.java:182)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
    ontainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
   .java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer
   .java:247)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectSc
     anContainer.java:242)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanC
    ontainer.java:232)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
   ontainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
     .java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:
   86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentC
    ontainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer
   .java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContain
   er.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.exec
   ute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
   sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(Iso
  latedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner
   .java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScann
    er.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
   ERROR:
   ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug       logging
```

in addition when I run with simple two or three page app sonarqube sever has worked well. could anyone help me please

Comment: Could you check the server logs please (see logs/sonar.log) ?

Comment: I checked but I dont understand it that what it is trying to display

Comment: In that case please provide these logs. Thanks

Comment: please do not mix topics in the same thread.

Comment: sure, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: does that mean that the initial error is resolved ?

Comment: yes, it is resolved

Comment: Good news. Can you add an answer to mark the question as resolved please ?